# Unique solution of nolinear equation set

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, systems-of-equations

$$\left\{
\begin{aligned}
f_1(x_1,x_2...x_n)=0 \\
f_2(x_1,x_2...x_n)=0 \\
\vdots \\
f_n(x_1,x_2...x_n)=0
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
$f_i\in C^\infty(R^n)$,what is the condition that make the equation set has unique solution? In fact ,I think the $f_i\in C^\infty(R^n)$ can be changed to $f_i\in C^2(R^n)$.

Answer (score 0):

One sufficient condition is that $f$ is injective. By the [inverse function theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem), it suffices to prove that the differential $Df = (\displaystyle \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j})$ is invertible. In fact, you only need that $f_i$ are $C^1$, and the differential is invertible.

As noted in the comments, this shows that the system has at most one solution. It does not imply that a solution exists.

Comment: That may show the system has at most one solution, but it won't guarantee that it has a solution.

Comment: Yes, that's true.